# Hue dashboard not loading

Tags: solr, cloudera, dashboard, hue

I have a Hue instance running, connected to a Solr Server. The standard dashboard (gridster enabled) works perfectly. However, upon disabling gridster, the dashboard will not load; it just has the loading wheel on it. Are there any fixes for this problem?

Comment: If you disable Gridster, you would need to create fresh new dashboard. In recent version it might not be possible to disable it.

Comment: @Romain ,thank you for your responce, I did create a new dashboard, both a new document > new dashboard, and just by right clicking on the index and new dashboard. In gridster would there be a way to display widgets in a column - as currently they have to be below the other widgets